# Weex handles string object differently from Node.js

Tags: v8, weex

I got a script compiled from ClojureScript with contains mainly 
 `(pr-str {})`https://gist.github.com/jiyinyiyong/b393091830f6722c40d5c632f828b373

As I run the js file with `node main.js`, it prints `LOOKING {}`. But when I load the file in Weex, it's `[object Object]`. So what happened in Weex's V8 engine?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time tracing down the bug. It appears that after Weex decided to froze global variables, `Object.prototype` is locked. And ClojureScript is using Closure Library which is assigning to prototype. Not very strange use case but it triggers problem in Weex `0.10.0`.

I can't say it's fixed, but it appears that freezing global Objects comes with prices.